# EclipsePydev 4.4.0+ tkinter debugging Error

Tags: python, eclipse, tkinter, pydev

In the past 1.5 year I have developed a quite big code using Python 2.7.8 (Anaconda accelerate) and Tkinter with quite some satisfaction. I have being using Eclipse Luna + pydev and everything was running smooth. Then some time ago I have performed (my error) an update and I have updated pydev, since then the debugger stack and bug consistently. I'll try to be more specific: in my code a main window open a second window that runs a chunk of code using `threading` python library (in order to still have the window active); now when I debug this portion of the code a strange small TK window appears  and the debugger stacks.
I have tried to upgrade to Eclipse Mars but I get the same error....I believe due to pydev.

Comment: Now I'm sure that is pydev the issue in fact I have unstalled pydev 4.4.0 and manually installed pydev 4.3.0 and the bug disapears...everything run smooth again...

Comment: I will try it for a while and I'll see if i don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Maybe if update to python 2.7.10 the problem will be solved too...I should give a try...